# Kubernetes containerd - failed to pull image from private registry

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, harbor

I setup kubernetes V1.20.1 with `containerd` instead of Docker. Now I failed to pull Docker images from my private registry (Harbor).

I already changed the /etc/containerd/config.toml like this:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
      endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."registry.foo.com"]
      endpoint = ["https://registry.foo.com"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry.foo.com"]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry.foo.com".auth]
        username = "admin"
        password = "Harbor12345"
```

But this did not work. The pull failed with the message:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.foo.com/library/myimage:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown
desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.foo.com/library/myimage:latest": failed to 
resolve reference "registry.foo.com/library/myimage:latest": unexpected status code 
[manifests latest]: 401 Unauthorized
```

My Harbor registry is available via HTTPS with a Let's Encrypt certificate. So https should not be the problem here.

Even if I try to create a docker-secret this did not work:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry registry.foo.com --docker-server=https://registry.foo.com --docker-username=admin --docker-password=Harbor12345 --docker-email=info@foo.com
```

Can anybody give me an example how to configure a private registry in Kubernetes with containerd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `imagePullSecrets` in the pod/deployment specification:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: registry.foo.com
```

More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: I get this working with a 'Pod'. But it did not work with a 'Deployment'.

Comment: ok - it worked after I created the secret for the corresponding namespace. Is there any way to add the imagePullScrets on a global area, so that I do not need a secret for every namespace?

Comment: Secrets can only be referenced by Pods in that same namespace: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#details
However if you use solutions like Rancher, you could configure the secret on the project level and all namespaces in that project would have access to the secret..

Answer (score 1):

Create file, put username:password in it and get the base64 code of it:

```
touch pass.txt 
nano pass.txt
# write like that => username:password 
base64 pass.txt
# get the base64 code: cmxxxxxxxxyyyyyyCg==
```

nano /etc/containerd/config.toml (use auth="", instead of using username/password):

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
      endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."registry.foo.com"]
      endpoint = ["https://registry.foo.com"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry.foo.com".tls] 
       insecure_skip_verify=true
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry.foo.com".auth]
        auth ="cmxxxxxxxxyyyyyyCg=="
```

Restart containerd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart containerd.service
```

Pull image directly from node:

```
sudo crictl pull registry.foo.com/imageName:Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry ecr-registry-secret \
--docker-server=<account-id>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com \
--docker-username=AWS \
--docker-password=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1) \
--docker-email=unused
```

Comment: Would be good if you could explain why this would solve the problem, asking somebody to run some code without this isn't as helpful especially to other users of the site

Comment: And then do what?